# How to combine two 6 bit binary values to a 12bit binary value and convert to int?

Tags: java, binary, int

I have an ADC that outputs a 12bit value with each bit represented by true or false. How can I convert this into an int?

For example:

**12 Bit value is 111111000001**

```
//getLevel returns true or false
boolean bit0 = getLevel(channel0);//true
boolean bit1 = getLevel(channel1);//true
boolean bit2 = getLevel(channel2);//true
boolean bit3 = getLevel(channel3);//true
boolean bit4 = getLevel(channel4);//true
boolean bit5 = getLevel(channel5);//true
boolean bit6 = getLevel(channel6);//false
boolean bit7 = getLevel(channel7);//false
boolean bit8 = getLevel(channel8);//false
boolean bit9 = getLevel(channel9);//false
boolean bit10 = getLevel(channe10);//false
boolean bit11 = getLevel(channe11);//true


///do something to convert bit0 - bit11 to an int == 4033
```

Any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the bits in a BitSet.

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet();
//set the bit fields...

//convert bitset to integer
int bitInteger = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < bits.length(); i++) {
    if(bits.get(i)) {
        bitInteger |= (1 << i);   //logical OR each bit into the integer and shift left
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! I'd vote but I don't have enough rep yet.